# Flot : Get the x axis offset while drawing markings

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

I am trying to add a delete button to my flot chart which deletes the marking that is drawn. In order to place this button, i would need to set the offset for the image(both top and left).

Scenario 1: After the chart is drawn, on click of a datapoint in the chart, i draw a marking vertically. In this case i would like to get the proper left offset of the marking so that i can place a button on top of the marking. Something similar to the below screen shot.

[image: Sample of what i am trying to achieve]

Scenario 2: I have stored these clicked datapoints in my bean and when the graph is reloaded or refreshed, using these stored datapoints i create the markings again. At this time also i would like to know the left off set so that i can place the button again on top of this marking.

Here is the snippet of js i am trying to use.

```
$("#placeholder").bind("plotclick", function (event, pos, item) {

        if (item) {
            $("#clickdata").text(" - click point " + item.dataIndex + " in " + item.series.label);
            var p = item.datapoint[0];
            markings1.push({ xaxis: { from: item.datapoint[0], to: item.datapoint[0] }, color: "#EF4036" });

            $("#tooltip").remove();
            var div = $('<div id="d1">');
            var imid = "dp"+item.datapoint[0];

            var img = $('<img class="btn">'); //Equivalent: $(document.createElement('img'))


            img.attr('id', imid);
            img.attr('src', "http://megaicons.net/static/img/icons_sizes/8/178/256/editing-delete-icon.png");

            $("#"+imid).data('dp',item.datapoint[0]);
            img.appendTo("#d1");
            img.width(20);
            img.data('dp',item.datapoint[0]);
            img.height(20);
            img.offset({top: plot.offset().top-25, left: pos.pageX-10});
            div.appendTo('#placeholder');

            plot.draw();    

        }
    });
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Nice feature for the graph, I may use that sometime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this to get the x coordinate (relative to the page) of an x value in your graph:

```
var xPos = plot.offset().left + plot.getAxes().xaxis.p2c(xValue);
```

See the [documentation](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#plot-methods) for more info.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But, the value which i am not getting is not the same as pos.pageX which i am capturing using plotclick event. The marking is drawn at pos.pageX location but the plot.getAxes().xaxis.p2c(xValue) gives different value. Am i missing something here ?

Comment: Right, the value from `p2c()` is from the offset of the canvas, you have to add `plot.offset().left`.